# How to call angular materials api methods?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to reset a dragged cdkDrag component's position, and I noticed that there is a function doing this here https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to actually call it.

I have entered the cdkDrag onto a DOM like this:

```
<div cdkDrag ...> ... </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to read examples? https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: `CdkDrag` is actually declared as a _directive class_, not a method that can be called.